# How to load a list of numpy arrays to pytorch dataset loader?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a huge list of numpy arrays, where each array represents an image and I want to load it using torch.utils.data.Dataloader object. But the documentation of torch.utils.data.Dataloader mentions that it loads data directly from a folder. How do I modify it for my cause? I am new to pytorch and any help would be greatly appreciated.
my numpy array for a single image looks something like this. The image is RBG image.

```
[[[ 70  82  94]
  [ 67  81  93]
  [ 66  82  94]
  ..., 
  [182 182 188]
  [183 183 189]
  [188 186 192]]

 [[ 66  80  92]
  [ 62  78  91]
  [ 64  79  95]
  ..., 
  [176 176 182]
  [178 178 184]
  [180 180 186]]

 [[ 62  82  93]
  [ 62  81  96]
  [ 65  80  99]
  ..., 
  [169 172 177]
  [173 173 179]
  [172 172 178]]

 ...,
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

I think what DataLoader actually requires is an input that subclasses `Dataset`. You can either write your own dataset class that subclasses `Dataset`or use `TensorDataset` as I have done below:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

my_x = [np.array([[1.0,2],[3,4]]),np.array([[5.,6],[7,8]])] # a list of numpy arrays
my_y = [np.array([4.]), np.array([2.])] # another list of numpy arrays (targets)

tensor_x = torch.Tensor(my_x) # transform to torch tensor
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(my_y)

my_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) # create your datset
my_dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset) # create your dataloader
```

Works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to replicate this if there are memory limitations? I find myself running out of memory at the torch.stack step.

Comment: @Indrajit, sure thing, instead of using TensorDataset, just define your own Dataset class that loads a numpy array from file.

Comment: You don't need to use `toch.stack` with list comprehension. Instead you can use `torch.Tensor(my_x)` and `torch.Tensor(my_y)` directly.

Comment: @mbpaulus Can I load the numpy array in batches? That would help a lot on the memory issue.

Comment: And how to do the opposite operation? Convert from dataset/dataloader into list of numpy?

Answer (score 23):

Since you have images you probably want to perform transformations on them. So `TensorDataset` is not the best option here. Instead you can create your own `Dataset`. Something like this:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, targets, transform=None):
        self.data = data
        self.targets = torch.LongTensor(targets)
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        y = self.targets[index]
        
        if self.transform:
            x = Image.fromarray(self.data[index].astype(np.uint8).transpose(1,2,0))
            x = self.transform(x)
        
        return x, y
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

# Let's create 10 RGB images of size 128x128 and 10 labels {0, 1}
data = list(np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 3, 128, 128)))
targets = list(np.random.randint(2, size=(10)))

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(64), transforms.ToTensor()])
dataset = MyDataset(data, targets, transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5)
```

Comment: Where does `transforms` come from in the line `transform = transforms.Compose(...)`?

Comment: @AdamMurphy It comes from the `torchvision` package https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html

I fixed the answer by adding a line to the code which imports it.

Comment: It is kind of sad having to convert numpy arrays into PIL images before transforms.

Answer (score 10):

PyTorch `DataLoader` need a `DataSet` as you can check in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html). The right way to do that is to use:

```
torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(*tensors)
```

Which is a Dataset for wrapping tensors, where each sample will be retrieved by indexing tensors along the first dimension.
The parameters `*tensors` means tensors that have the same size of the first dimension.

The other `class torch.utils.data.Dataset` is an abstract class.

Here is how to convert numpy arrays to tensors:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(10)
print(n) #[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
t1 = torch.Tensor(n)  # as torch.float32
print(t1) #tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
t2 = torch.from_numpy(n)  # as torch.int32
print(t2) #tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=torch.int32)
```

The accepted answer used the `torch.Tensor` construct.
If you have an image with pixels from 0-255 you may use this:

```
timg = torch.from_numpy(img).float()
```

Or torchvision [`to_tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) method, that converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray to tensor.

---

But here is a little trick you can put your numpy arrays directly.

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
d1 = DataLoader( x1, batch_size=3)
```

This also works, but if you print `d1.dataset` type:

```
print(type(d1.dataset)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

While we actually need Tensors for working with CUDA so it is better to use Tensors to feed the `DataLoader`.

Comment: Hi, for the input of `DataLoader`, what's the difference between `np.array` with `tensor` ? I find that if the input `x1` if `np.array`, the `DataLoader` will  still output `tensor`, so I think using `np.array` data to feed `DataLoader` is same as using `tensor` data.

Comment: It is the same in effect. The only difference is we have a conversion in case we feed the numpy array.