# PyTorch - Convert CIFAR dataset to `TensorDataset`

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I train ResNet34 on CIFAR dataset. For a certain reason, I need to convert the dataset into `TensorDataset`.
My solution is based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44475689/15072863 with some differences (maybe they are critical, but I don't see why).
It looks I'm not doing this correctly.

Train loader:

```
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010))])

train_ds = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10('/files/', train=True, transform=transform_train, download=True)

xs, ys = [], []
for x, y in train_ds:
  xs.append(x)
  ys.append(y)

# 1) Standard Version
# cifar_train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)

# 2) TensorDataset version, seems to be incorrect
cifar_tensor_ds = TensorDataset(torch.stack(xs), torch.tensor(ys, dtype=torch.long))
cifar_train_loader = DataLoader(cifar_tensor_ds, batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)
```

I don't think it matters, but test loader is defined as usual:

```
transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010)),
])

cifar_test_loader = DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10('/files/', train=False, transform=transform_test, download=True),
  batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)
```

I know that something is wrong with how I use `TensorDataset`, since;

1. With `TensorDataset` I achieve 100% train accuracy, 80% test accuracy
2. With standard Dataset I achieve 99% train accuracy (never 100%), 90% test accuracy.

So, what am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:** My final goal is to split the dataset into 10 datasets based on their class. Is there a better way to do this? Of course, I can define my subclass of DataSet, but manually splitting it and creating `TensorDataset`'s seemed to be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the "standard" dataset, each time you load an image, a random transform (flip + crop) is applied to it. As a consequence, virtually every image of every epoch is unique, seen only once. So you kind of have `nb_epochs * len(dataset)` different inputs.

With your custom dataset, you first read all the images of the CIFAR dset (each of them with a random transform), store them all, and then use the stored tensor as your training inputs. Thus at each epoch, the network sees exactly the same inputs

Since the network was already able to achieve great accuracy with the random transformations, removing it makes it even easier and thus it further improves the accuracy

Oh, and you should definitely redefine you own subclass of Dataset. It's not even complicated, and it will be much easier to work with. You just need to extract the 10 different datasets, either by manually moving the images in their folders or using some reindexing arrays or something like that. Either way, you will only have to do it once, so not big deal

Comment: Thank you. I've specified wrong numbers in my post: testing accuracy was lower for `TensorDataset`. Your explanation makes sense.